# Pasar array de string como parámetro por @Url.Action en javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Tengo este controlador en c#:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("descargar-reportes")]
    public ActionResult Duplicar(int ide, string[] fechas){

    }
```

y le esto pasando estos parametros por javascript:

```
function descargar() {
            console.log(fechas_repo.length);
            var url = "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("descargar-reportes", "reportes", new { ide="param-id", fechas="param-fechas" }))";
            url = url.replace("param-id", encodeURIComponent(id_repo))
                    .replace("param-fechas", encodeURIComponent(fechas_repo));
                window.location.href = url;fechas_repo[0]);
            }
```

sin embargo el array de string me llega con un solo valor ya que en el controlador al hacer fechas.Length me devuelve 1 y solo me aparece una fecha.

por cierto el array que le paso si tiene mas de 1 valor ya que lo comprobe con console.log y tiene mas de 1 valor

Comment: La Acción de tu Controlador se llama `Duplicar`, y en el Url.Action llamas a la Acción `descargar-reportes`. Es esto un error de edición?

Comment: estoy utilizando route    [HttpGet]
        [Route("descargar-reportes")]

Comment: OK. Indica también que es `id_repo` y `fechas_repo`

Comment: que imprime console.log(url)??

Comment: en el console.log me imprime todos los valores del array

Answer (score 1):

Para enviar un Array a través el **QueryString** en ASP.NET MVC, debes hacerlo creando tantas variables como número de elementos tenga el `Array`. Sería algo así:

```
/reportes/descargar-reportes?ide="tu_ide"&fechas="fecha1"&fechas="fecha2"&fechas="fecha3"& ...
```

En tu caso, al utilizar `@Url.Action()`, puedes construir el QueryString a partir de un **`RouteValueDictionary`**.

La otra opción es construir los parámetros mediante un `foreach` o un `For`, recorriendo el Array.

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucione creando un QueryString con una funcion JavaScript.

```
function encodeQueryData(object)
{
    var parameters = [];
    for (var a in object) {
        if (object.hasOwnProperty(a)) {
            parameters.push(encodeURI('fechas' + '=' + object[a]));
        }
    }    
    return parameters.join('&');
}
```

y al llamar al @Url.Action lo hago de esta forma.

```
var url = "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("descargar-reportesats", "reporte-tarea", new { 
ide="param-id", fechas="param-fechas" }))";
url = url.replace("param-id", encodeURIComponent(id_repo))
      .replace("param-fechas", encodeQueryData(fechas_repo));
window.location.href = url;
```